# Filtering an array returned from Promise

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I am porting the following code:

```
function FindDevices() {
  let ports = portLister.list();
  let devices = []
  for (port of ports) {
    try {
      device = new Device(port); // throws if not valid port
      devices.push(device);
    }
    catch {
      // log(port); 
    }
  }
  return FindDevices;
}
```

Current version should use `SerialPort.list()`, which [returns a promise](https://serialport.io/docs/api-stream#serialportlist).

So far, I tried something along these lines, without success:

```
const SerialPort = require('serialport');

async function FindDevices() {
  const result = (await SerialPort.list()).filter(port => new Device(port));
  return result;
}

FindDevices().then(devices => {
  console.log(devices);
});
```

Obviously I am not quite getting what I should do. So the question is: how should I represent the same intent of former `FindDevices` function, using async/await or Promises? And what would be a good way of *consuming* that result? For example, how should I get the first found device?

Comment: what do you get in list results in `FindDevices` if you do `const results = (await SerialPort.list());console.log(results);`?

Comment: @Uma The intention is to receive a list of all _valid_ devices, but since not every serial port in a computer is a valid device (and this is the reason I put the device constructor in a try/catch block), something must be done to the list of _portNames_ returned from `list()` before returning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you do need to filter items based on failure, so you can add catch block in mapper and then filter out the results

```
async function FindDevices() {
  const ports = await SerialPort.list();
  const results = ports.map(port => {
    try {
      return new Device(port)
    } catch() {
      return null
    }
  }).filter(port => !!port);

  return results;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use the same function but with await?

```js
async function FindDevices() {
  const ports = await SerialPort.list();
  const devices = [];
  for (let port of ports) {
    try {
      const device = new Device(port); // throws if not valid port
      devices.push(device);
    } catch {
      // log(port); 
    }
  }
  return devices;
}
```

Comment: I know `filter` is not the proper operation, but I think `map` isn't either. For each `portName` returned by `list()` I must first check if I can instantiate a device. In the example, the constructor is inside a try/catch block.

Comment: Is there something wrong with your initial for loop then? Just use it after await.

Answer (score 0):

Just await on resolver for SerialPorts with all the actions performed, and resolve Promise with your devices if needed

```js
function portListener() {
  this.list = function() {
      return Promise.resolve([80,443,4200,4300]);
  }
}

class Device
{
  constructor(port)
  {
    this.port = port;
  }
}

async function FindDevices() {
    var devices = [];
    await new portListener().list().then(function(ports) {
    for (port of ports) {
      try {
        device = new Device(port); // throws if not valid port
        devices.push(device);
      }
      catch {
        // log(port); 
      }
    }
  });
  return Promise.resolve(devices);
}

FindDevices().then(function(devices) {
  console.log(devices);
});
```